# Using letsencrypt & certbot how do I add a mail server to an existing certificate?

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, email-server

**Host:** Digital Ocean

**OS:** CentOS

I have an existing SSL certificate that covers my domain.

`$ certbot certificates` produces this output.

```
Found the following certs:
   Certificate Name: example.com
     Domains: example.com www.example.com
     Expiry Date: 2020-04-12 21:20:31+00:00 (VALID: 86 days)
     Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
     Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

I installed `postfix` and I believe I need to add *mail.example.com* to my certificate.

I tried to add *mail.example.com* to my certificate using this command,

`$ sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d mail.example.com`

Unfortunately it threw this error,

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mail.example.com
Waiting for verification…
Challenge failed for domain mail.example.com
http-01 challenge for mail.example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:

The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: mail.example.com
Type: dns
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for mail.example.com
```

It appears that certbot is trying to install *mail.example.com* using an A record.  On Digital Ocean in my Domain Records section *mail.example.com* was created as an MX record, not an A record.

Comment: i think nxdomain is telling you that the address couldn't be resolved

Comment: Per RFC 2606 and RFC 6761 please use example.com or example.org when obfuscating your domain. (I'm assuming you don't actually own testsite.com .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that for mail delivery you need an MX- entry. BUT: mail.testsite.com is a fully qualified hostname. And you need to tell everybody who wants to deliver mail to you what the ip address of this hostname is. So you need an A record as well, pointing to the server where you want to receive the mail.

Create the a record and point to your mail server and run certbot from that machine. Make sure, that a webserver is responding on port 80 for mail.testsite.com for the verification to be successfull. Then it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Do it like this:

```
$ sudo certbot -d mail.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

A DNS TXT record will be printed (just don't click *enter* yet), publish it to your DNS and wait till you're sure that the TXT record can be read from outside of your DNS then click *enter* and it will be verified.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. Can that TXT record be removed afterwords or does it need to remain permanently?

Comment: @GreatBlakes YW..... Once the authorization status is valid then you can clear it, but better leave it for future queries.

Answer (score 0):

If Ionos is your DNS provider and you follow the common convention of calling your mail server mail.example.com, it's not sufficient to create an A record "mail" and an MX record "mail".  Your TXT record doesn't satisfy certbot.

You must create a *subdomain* called "mail" using the Ionos UI.  Then you can navigate to that subdomain in the UI, create your TXT record and call it "_acme-challenge".  That produces a working "_acme-challenge.mail.example.com" TXT record.

> better leave it for future queries

It looks to me as if the value in the challenge changes each time you run certbot.  So you can leave the TXT record in place but you will have to edit it each time.